# Haskell - How the construct do calls fail function from Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, syntactic-sugar, list-definition

While studying [Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-list-monad) I understood why when pattern matching on **list definitions** fails, its computation is somewhat "ignored" instead of throwing an error:

```
test :: [(Int, Int)]
test = [(x, y) | (Just x) <- [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3], y <- [1, 2]]

*Main> test
[(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)]
```

It's because it is just a **syntactic sugar** for a `Monad` application using `do`:

```
test'' :: [(Int, Int)]
test'' = do
  (Just x) <- [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
  y <- [1, 2]
  return (x, y)

*Main> test'
[(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)]
*Main> test == test'
True
```

Similarly, we could try to resemble this logic using the **bind operator** `>>=`:

```
test'' :: [(Int, Int)]
test'' = [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3] >>= \(Just x) -> [1, 2] >>= \y -> return (x, y)
```

However, as expected, the monadic function `fail` relative to `List` will not be called in this situation like it was in the previous ones:

```
*Main> test''
[(1,1),(1,2)*** Exception: test.hs:11:40-82: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

So, my question is: **Is it possible to get `[(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)]` using `test''` style, in a neat way? Is `do` construct a syntactic sugar for something like this?**

```
test'' :: [(Int, Int)]
test'' = [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3] >>= \maybeX -> [1, 2] >>= \y -> case maybeX of Just x -> return (x, y)
                                                                                  _      -> fail undefined

*Main> test''
[(1,1),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)]
*Main> test'' == test
True
```

Comment: You can see precise description of translation of `do` expressions to function calls in https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

test'' = [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3] >>= \case
            Just x -> [1, 2] >>= \y -> return (x, y)
            _ -> fail "..."
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know yet about this `LambdaCase` extension, and I could have used the `case` in the middle. Just a detail, you forgot the argument to `fail` in the last line from of your answer